# Containerizing Azure Function keeps failing to run

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-functions, containers

I just created a dummy azure function with default flavor. Here is my Dockerfile default from VS.
[image]
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1.csproj", "FunctionApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp1"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

SO I executed these 2 lines of code to create the docker file which works perfectly fine for API project but not for Azure Function project.

```
docker build -t function1 -f FunctionApp1/Dockerfile .

docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name FunctionApp1_sample function1:latest
```

It keeps throwing error below

```
The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
      Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
       ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_ContainerClient() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 83
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobClient(String timerName, Boolean createContainerIfNotExists) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 155
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 94
```

I also have tried to set the following environment variable explicitly in the Docker file and still not working. any Suggestions? Thanks.

```
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    AzureWebJobsStorage="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" \
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=dotnet
```

Comment: There are docker images specific to azure functions. You should probably utilize one of those: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions

Comment: may i know what you need to put at the beginning of the docker file? this one does not work. thanks

FROM registry.hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions AS base

Comment: You would do something like `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4`. Microsoft docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

By following the MS Doc given by @[*peinearydevelopment*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874522/peinearydevelopment), I have built the function app with the docker file and published to docker container and then to Azure Function App. Also, enabled the continuous deployment along with SSH Connection.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 harikr572/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
```

[image]

[image]

**Docker File**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0  AS  installer-env

 
# Build requires 3.1 SDK

COPY  --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1  /usr/share/dotnet  /usr/share/dotnet

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0-appservice
COPY  .  /src/dotnet-function-app

RUN  cd  /src/dotnet-function-app  &&  \
mkdir  -p  /home/site/wwwroot  &&  \
dotnet  publish  *.csproj  --output  /home/site/wwwroot

  
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
ENV  AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot  \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

 
COPY  --from=installer-env  ["/home/site/wwwroot",  "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure ***timer*** functions are *dependent* on a storage container to connect to. The timer trigger uses a storage lock to ensure that there is only one timer instance when a function app scales out to multiple instances.

The error: `---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor` is in reference to this inability to utilize the BlobContainerClient to connect. You do not have storage specified.

You need to configure storage in the function app settings, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobssecretstoragesas

In your Dockerfile you set `AzureWebJobsStorage="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` so the function is expecting local storage emulation using Azurite, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite

You *most likely* did not enable Azurite for a runtime storage account when creating the project in Visual Studio. This is possible in Visual Studio 2022+.

For development storage to be accessible in your docker container, you would need to install Azurite in your container. For example, could add the following ***pseudo-code*** in your Dockerfile:

```
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install Azurite Blob Storage
RUN npm install -g azurite
```

You also need to start the blob host with:

```
# Start Azurite Blob Storage
CMD ["azurite-blob", "--blobHost", "0.0.0.0", "--blobPort", "10000"]
```

That all said, you'd most likely just want to provision a storage account in Azure and connect to that. Easier setup and more performant.

OR

Run Azurite locally instead of in the container and point your container to use your desktop host.

Hope this helps!